# making GIF animation from "movie" command

Tags: matlab

how is possible to make and save(export) animated GIF picture from "movie" command?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-48KECO/index.html?solution=1-48KECO

Answer (score 2):

The function [MOVIE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/movie.html) will only *play* a movie, not save one. To save an animated GIF you should use the function [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html). There is an example of how to do this on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/): [Animated GIF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21944-animated-gif) by [Robert Bemis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/5021).